# How to integrate stencil into Next.js 14 for SSR not CSR?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, web-component, next.js13, stenciljs

I need to integrate my stencil web components library into Next.js 14 projects to achieve server side rendering (SSR), not CSR because I could achive that using the `react output target`.

I've tried to hydrate the stencil components by following the instructions in the [official documentation](https://stenciljs.com/docs/hydrate-app#hydrate-app), but did not work because of that the components generated by the `react output target` are not being hydrated, so how to hydrate those components. or any alternative approaches for integration.